# Создание таблицы бд из xml (xsd)

Tags: c#, sqlite

Возможно ли в SQLite создать таблицы на основе xsd и заполнить их данными из xml? По аналогии с sqlxml 4.0 (SQLXMLBulkLoad) в MS SQL. Заполнение происходит из приложения на C#.

Answer (score 1):

http://xsd2db.sourceforge.net/
Да, с помощью этой утилиты вы можете создать базу данных по xsd.
Ну а далее ее заполняете из xml либо десериализуете xml и загоняете в базу.